# What does "incorporated" mean in the TV show "Kids Incorporated"?

Tags: word-meaning

Someone recommended this show for my kids. *Kids Incorporated* is the name of a rock group of children. What does *incorporated* suggest in the title? I understand incorporate is similar to include, but what does it mean for the kids to be included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means: incorporated **as in** an incorporated company, a company that has been registered as a corporation (AmE) or as a company (BrE).

In other words, it's as if children had created an official company: Kids Incorporated or Kids, Inc.

For real companies, you often see: Name of company, Inc.

It's like a company of kids. They are trying to be funny.

In other words, the show is all about kids and by kids. The word incorporate does not refer to the word include. It refers to the idea of a company of kids.